# Download data.zip programmatically for "Loophole-free Bell-inequality violation using electron spins separated by 1.3 kilometres" experiment

Tags: python, database, python-requests, download

I would like to create a gist or a Jupyter notebook analyzing the data located at [Loophole-free Bell-inequality violation using electron spins separated by 1.3 kilometres](https://data.4tu.nl/articles/dataset/Loophole-free_Bell-inequality_violation_using_electron_spins_separated_by_1_3_kilometres/12703235/1). The site has this download button

[image]

which right-clicking to copy-paste the link tells me it associated with the URL `https://data.4tu.nl/ndownloader/files/24056582`. If I copy-paste this URL into Firefox it downloads the file. I would like to do this with Python.

I figured I would try making a request to that link with the following.

```py
import requests
requests.get('https://data.4tu.nl/ndownloader/files/24056582')
```

But the above did not seem to download `data.zip` as desired. How can I use Python to programmatically download `data.zip` into the local path of my Python script?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/674004/availability-of-dataset-from-loophole-free-bell-inequality-violation-using-elec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests

r = requests.get("https://data.4tu.nl/ndownloader/files/24056582")

with open("data.zip", "wb") as f_out:
    f_out.write(r.content)
```

This downloads the `data.zip`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 152913 okt 17 00:35 data.zip
```